# What does "resp." mean in these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The abbreviation *resp.* has been used a number of times in the following paragraph:

> For each of these problems (resp., tools), we start by presenting the
>   natural concern underlying it (resp., its intuitive objective), then
>   define the problem (resp., tool), and finally demonstrate that the
>   problem can be solved (resp., the tool can be constructed).

I am trying to understand what *resp.* means here (and many more times in the same book).

Trying to search using Google only confused me more, there are so many options.

Also please see [this answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070502205656AAIIHzZ), which says that *"resp." means "namely"*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suspect this is a mistranslation of German *bzw.* = *beziehungsweise*, which can mean either *respectively* or *or as the case may be*. The translator has taken a passage in which the latter sense is intended and substituted the conventional abbreviation of the former sense.

The latter sense has no convenient one-word English translation, much less an abbreviation. I have often regretted this, because *bzw.* is so useful.

It sort of works, but not so gracefully, if you just substitute *or* for *resp.*

> For each of these problems (or tools), we start by presenting the natural concern underlying it (or its intuitive objective), then define the problem (or tool), and finally demonstrate that the problem can be solved (or the tool can be constructed).

Comment: In a fair amount of mathematics or computer science technical texts that I have seen it is used in this way as an abbreviation for respectively.

Comment: Also: the preposition "re." can be used in similar contexts which generally means "in respect of", or "in the matter of", and is synonyms with "regarding". For example "For each of the problems (re tools), we start by presenting the natural concern underlying it (re its intuitive objective) then define ...". It's a little clumsy, but then that clumsiness is inherited from the excessive bracketing of the original text.

Comment: several of my physics teachers used WRT (with respect to) in similar situations.

Comment: I am editing an English language help file that was written by native German speakers, and it is full of 'resp'. In each case, replacing 'resp.' with 'or' provides a meaningful English sentence, so I believe StoneyB's answer is correct when dealing with material translated from German.

Comment: @StoneyB, Wouldn't "**e.g.**" be a suitable alternative for bzw?

Comment: @Pacerier No: *e.g.* is *exempli gratia*, "for example".

Comment: I see this from German linguists writing about Irish or Old Irish. For an English speaker it makes no sense at all, e.g. “t̢ʹ, d̢ʹ represent intermediate sounds between tʹ and kʹ resp. dʹ and gʹ.”

Answer (score 11):

If the writer intends "*resp.*" to mean "*namely*", then it's wrong. That abbreviation is *viz.* for *[videlicet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/videlicet)*. I've never seen "*resp.*" used to mean "*namely*", and you'll notice that the answer you link to has received no votes for the 6 years since it was posted. One can only infer that this is what the writer intended.

According to the Merriam-Webster's New Unabridged Dictionary (3rd edition):

> Main Entry:resp
>   Function:abbreviation
>
> 1 respective; respectively
>   2 respiration; respiratory
>   3 respondent

The [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resp.) online says:

> resp. abbr.
>   1. respective
>   2. respectively
>   The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.

And [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resp.) says:

> resp.
>   1. respective.
>   2. respectively.
>   3. respelled; respelling.
>   4. respondent.
>   Dictionary.com Unabridged. Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2013.

Comment: On what do you base the assumption that it's intended to mean "namely"? I ask sincerely. :)

Answer (score 10):

It's not being used in a standard way.  If I had to guess, I'd say it was written by a native speaker of German using *respectively* as an incorrect translation of *beziehungsweise*, abbreviated to *resp*.  I base this guess largely on the following blog post:

[Resp. and other non-existent English words](http://transblawg.eu/2004/02/26/resp-and-other-non-existent-english-wordsnicht-existente-englische-worter/)

This usage isn't a normal part of English, but by all accounts it seems that the *"namely"* gloss is correct.

Comment: Are you and I chained together tonight?!

Comment: A stone (or at least something stoney) chained to a boat (or at least something boaty)? Good luck!

Comment: @LeonMeier Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the link to point to the new URL.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that "resp." was intended to mean "respectively".  The sentence is intended to convey the following two sentences without writing the common parts out twice:

> For each of these problems, we start by presenting the natural concern underlying it, then define the problem, and finally demonstrate that the problem can be solved.
>
> For each of these tools, we start by presenting its intuitive objective, then define the tool, and finally demonstrate that the tool can be constructed.

I am not sure whether this is considered correct usage of "respectively", though I have seen it used this way in some technical (mathematical) texts.

Comment: This is fairly common in mathematical and computer science texts, in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

The German connection others have raised is a good explanation for why I'd never seen this structure until a few years back. However, it's out there and in use now. It means, *or can be taken to mean*, "respectively", in much the same way that it's normally used in English.

The normal use for "respectively" is to signify that the items of two (or more) lists are meant to correspond to each other in one-to-one fashion. For example:

> The hunters and gatherers brought meat and tubers, respectively.

This means that the hunters brought meat, and the gatherers brought tubers.

Now, the use of "resp." is a little bit different, but the purpose is the same. Instead of coming after the later list, it comes between items in each list. So your example:

> For each of these problems (resp., tools), we start by presenting the natural concern underlying it (resp., its intuitive objective), then define the problem (resp., tool), and finally demonstrate that the problem can be solved (resp., the tool can be constructed).

...means that:

- For each *problem*, we present the *concern*, define the *problem*, and demonstrate that it can be *solved*; and
- For each *tool*, we present its *objective*, define the *tool*, and demonstrate that it can be *constructed*.

Answer (score 3):

Other posters who point out that this is a common error of Germans writing in English seem to be correct.  I have encountered this error myself.  Based on the examples, and others' likely correct assertion that the intended meaning is "namely", a term that would fit well in the context of the example is "i.e.".

Conveniently, this is also an abbreviation.

Example:
For each of these problems (i.e., tools), we start by presenting the natural concern underlying it (i.e., its intuitive objective), then define the problem (i.e., tool), and finally demonstrate that the problem can be solved (i.e., the tool can be constructed).

Comment: This works as a translation but does not fully capture what the likely German original 'beziehungsweise' actually means. Other answers do a good job of that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It means respectively. 
I'm a French scientist, and we use it a lot in French ("resp." = "respectivement"). We then tend to abuse of it, when writing scientific articles in English...

Comment: I am trying to infer its meaning in a text written by a native French speaker. I understand its meaning (I think) when used twice "wheels (resp. legs) are important for cars (resp. horses)". But how is it used if it only appears once? E.g. "We calculate the product (resp. sum) of the numbers." Can it be interpreted as meaning "in contrast to" or "as opposed to"? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

It means "respectively", which is a way to combine two sentences into one by substituting something for something else.